# Formatting table with siunitx: problem with special format

Tags: tables, formatting, siunitx

I need to create a table which aligns the numbers in a specific format, if x is none or a digit it would look like that: (xxx, xxx) (the first xxx could also be a negative number). What I want to do is align the entries in a column by the comma and maintain the space after the comma and I don't have a clue how to do that.

I also had a look at the [siunitx handbook](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

If anyone could help me, I'd be really lucky.

Currently it looks like this:
[image: Wrong alignment]

And here's a minimum example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx, booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\sisetup{
input-symbols = {()},
table-number-alignment = center,
table-figures-integer  = 2,
parse-numbers=false,
locale = DE
}

\begin{tabular}{@{}cS[separate-uncertainty, table-figures-uncertainty = 1]ll@{}}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}           & Mean            &                       &                       \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Lead Time} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} \\ \midrule
0                              & (-10, 11)              & (-25, 116)              & (21, 240)               \\
1                              & (11, 252)               & (22, 139)               & (24, 244)               \\
2                              & (63, 390)               & (48, 21)               & (47, 27)               \\
3                              & (66, 790)               & (68, 24)               & (150, 31)              \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `sidewaystable` is not defined in your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), could you add the necessary package/definition to make the code compilable.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. It's in the rotating package and just rotates the table so it's sideways

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you're trying to achieve is not clear at all. What is `siunitx` supposed to  add, as compared to the `l` columns?

Comment: I edited the description, I hope it's now more clear. I normally use the siunitx package to align normal numbers so I thought I could also use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that (a) uses an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment -- this will generate typographically correct `-` minus symbols -- and (b) spares you the tedium of having to type all those opening and closing parentheses.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, array, amsmath, rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{} c *{3}{>{(}r @{,\,} r<{)}} @{}}
\toprule
\text{Lead Time} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\text{Mean}} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-7}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{3} \\
\midrule
0        & -10 &  11 & -25 & 116 &  21 & 240 \\
1        &  11 & 252 &  22 & 139 &  24 & 244 \\
2        &  63 & 390 &  48 &  21 &  47 &  27 \\
3        &  66 & 790 &  68 &  24 & 150 &  31 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wohoo great, that's exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx, booktabs}

\newcommand{\lparen}{(}
\newcommand{\rparen}{)}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{
  table-align-text-pre=false,
  table-align-text-post=false,
}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=1.0]
  >{\lparen}S[table-format=-2.0,table-space-text-pre=(]
  @{,\,}
  S[table-format=3.0,table-space-text-post=)]<{\rparen}
  >{\lparen}S[table-format=-2.0,table-space-text-pre=(]
  @{,\,}
  S[table-format=3.0,table-space-text-post=)]<{\rparen}
  >{\lparen}S[table-format=3.0,table-space-text-pre=(]
  @{,\,}
  S[table-format=3.0,table-space-text-post=\rparen]<{\rparen}
  @{}l@{}
}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{6}{c}{Mean} \\
{Lead Time} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3} \\
\midrule
0         & -10 &  11 & -25 & 116 &  21 & 240 &\\
1         &  11 & 252 &  22 & 139 &  24 & 244 &\\
2         &  63 & 390 &  48 &  21 &  47 &  27 &\\
3         &  66 & 790 &  68 &  24 & 150 &  31 &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, than you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

The simplest way to obtain above table is not use `siunitx`. I put table in standard `table` environment. If you liek to have as `sidewaystable`, then just add missing package and change `table` to `sidewaystable`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\ml[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\text{#1}}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\text{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\[
\begin{array}{@{}c *{3}{r@{\ } l}}
\ml{}           & \mc{Mean}             &           &       &           &       \\
\ml{Lead Time}  & \mc{1}                & \mc{2}            & \mc{3}            \\ 
    \midrule
    0           & (-10,     & 11)       & (-25,     & 116)  & (21,      & 240)  \\
    1           & (11,      & 252)      & (22,      & 139)  & (24,      & 244)  \\
    2           & (63,      & 390)      & (48,      & 21)   & (47,      & 27)   \\
    3           & (66,      & 790)      & (68,      & 24)   & (150,     & 31)   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that's nearly what I'd like to achieve but the parenthesis should also be aligned so that within a column they look the same

Comment: Consider using an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. That way, negative numbers will be printed with proper mathematical minus symbols rather than with short text-mode dash symbols.

Comment: @Mico, again you remember me on `array` environment ... It seems that I'm not the best student ... :)